# Can someone interpret my Binary Cross Entropy Loss Curve?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, classification

[Binary Cross Entropy Loss Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvplU.png)

I am trying to understand my loss curve using : tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()

Question 1:
Based on my loss curve/accuracy, would it be wise to proceed to feed it into a ensemble learning model alongside with other 10 similar binary classification model?

Question 2:
I would know the reason why the apparent divergence between train / validation and whether is it a good/bad thing or any room for improvement/unrepresentative data

Question 3:
(I understand mse/mae loss curve divergence/convergence; are they similar too in terms of interpretation?)

Tried looking around for learning loss curve but only found mse/mae interpretation so far but barely anything about BinaryCrossentropy. could someone help me please? TIA

Comment: This is a site for programming questions, but your question doesn't contain any code. You'd probably do better asking on [datascience.se]